# pass form to server : using Java form : PHP & SQL Server

Tags: java, php, httprequest

I'm trying to pass value from java to php page, but i don't know how to write java code. Help me out.

My php code **java_post.php** works pretty fine

```
<?php 
  $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'student');
  if(!$connect) die ("Error connecting");

  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO admin(email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$password')";

  if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
  echo "Added successfully";
  }
  $connect->close();
?>
```

I try to input in console

java code :

```
public class POST {

  private static Scanner in;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {

    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String email = null;
    String passwor= null;
    System.out.println("Enter you email : ");
    email = in.next();
    System.out.println("Enter you password :");
    passwor = in.next();

    String urlLink = "http://localhost/java/java_post.php";
    String urlLink = "http://localhost/java/java_post.php";

    URL url = new URL(urlLink);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");


    --- ??  -- 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a third party http client instead of doing raw java: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/